# Angular/OIDC - undefined user after login

Tags: angular, typescript, openid-connect

I am creating an app using angular with IdentityServer SSO provider in ASP.NET.

I am able to log the user in and get the user info from auth server:
[User info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lGfk.png)

And this is the method that is called when SSO redirects user back after login (the console.log is what shows the user info on previous image):

```
//Auth service
async completeAuthentication()
  {
    this.user = await this.manager.signinRedirectCallback();
    console.log(this.user);
    this.authNavStatusSource.next(this.isAuthenticated());
  }
```

So in this place I have the user defined and everything should be ok but when I try to use the user username in header it shows up us undefined:
[Undefined user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mk66.png)

And this is place where the console.log is called:

```
//Header component
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.authService.authNavStatus$.subscribe(status => this.isAuthenticated = status);
    this.name = this.authService.username; //this is pr
  }

//Auth service
get username(): string
  {
    console.log(this.user);
    return this.user != null ? this.user.profile.preferred_username : '';
  }
```

Here are full files for auth service and header component:

```
auth.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserManager, User } from 'oidc-client';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { BaseService } from '../services/base.service';
import { ConfigService } from '../services/config.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService extends BaseService {

  private authNavStatusSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  authNavStatus$ = this.authNavStatusSource.asObservable();

  private manager = new UserManager
  ({
    authority: this.configService.AuthAppUri,
    client_id: 'angular_spa',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200',
    response_type: "code",
    scope: "openid profile email api.read",
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true
  });

  private user: User | null;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService)
  { 
    super();

    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.authNavStatusSource.next(this.isAuthenticated());
    });
  }

  login(userName?: string)
  {
    let extraQueryParams = userName ?
    {
      userName: userName
    } : {};

    return this.manager.signinRedirect
    ({
      extraQueryParams
    });
  }

  async completeAuthentication()
  {
    this.user = await this.manager.signinRedirectCallback();
    this.authNavStatusSource.next(this.isAuthenticated());
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean
  {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
  }

  get authorizationHeaderValue(): string
  {
    return this.user ? `${this.user.token_type} ${this.user.access_token}` : null;
  }

  get username(): string
  {
    console.log(this.user);
    return this.user != null ? this.user.profile.preferred_username : '';
  }

  async logout()
  {
    await this.manager.signoutRedirect();
  }
}
```

```
header.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../core/authentication/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  template: `
    <div class="navbar is-primary">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <div class="navbar-item" routerLink="/">
          LOGO
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-burger has-text-centered">
          MENU
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <a class="navbar-item" routerLink="/gameslist">Games</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" routerLink="/login" *ngIf="!isAuthenticated"><b>Login</b></a>
          <a class="navbar-item" routerLink="" *ngIf="isAuthenticated"><b>{{name}}</b></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [ 
    '.navbar{ border-style: solid; border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px; }'
  ]
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  name: string;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.authService.authNavStatus$.subscribe(status => this.isAuthenticated = status);
    this.name = this.authService.username;
  }

  async logout()
  {
    await this.authService.logout();
  }

  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Why can't I use user in my header? What's interesting is that I used the same get username() method in home component and it works just fine so I really have no idea why can't I get it to work in header component.

Comment: **Be careful**: in the image you make your token public.
I think it's ok because you don't give your server address, but if you do it in another question, some 'smart guy' could try to do some mischief...

Comment: @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero yeah, I know. Right now it didn't matter so I didn't bother hiding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you actually can use *username* in your header.
The problem, is that you are probably using it before it is 'instantiated'.

Try to insert this.name asignation inside the subscribtion, see how it goes:

```
this.subscription = this.authService.authNavStatus$
.subscribe(
   status => {this.isAuthenticated = status;
   this.name = this.authService.username;
});
```